USB not reconnected after added 2 new USB drive
first of all thanks for your time.
Now, i've a Raspberry with nextcloudpi mounted.
Until this afternoon all was ok with 2 USB Disk of 2TB attached (with power supply dedicated).
This afternoon i've addedd 2 new USB disk of 4TB added as GPT Partition for each.
I've worked for many times until 19.00. Now i've rebooted Raspberry and no USB is connected.
With sudo dmeg i receive following messages:
....
[   71.647116] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   71.647141] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   71.647277] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   71.647298] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   71.662908] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[   71.663149] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   71.665075] scsi host1: uas_eh_device_reset_handler FAILED to get lock err -19
[   71.665103] sd 1:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[   71.665118] sd 1:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[   71.665131] sd 1:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[   71.665143] sd 1:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[   71.665156] sd 1:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[   71.665168] sd 1:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[   71.665180] sd 1:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[   71.665219] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x03 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=67s
[   71.665239] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 01 00
[   71.665253] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   71.665277] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 1, async page read
[   71.665344] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[   71.665363] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   71.665384] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[   71.665481] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#27 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x03 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=67s
[   71.665500] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#27 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 01 00
[   71.665514] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   71.665533] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 2, async page read
[   71.665572] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x03 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=67s
[   71.665589] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 01 00
[   71.665602] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 3 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   71.665620] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 3, async page read
[   71.665656] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x03 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=67s
[   71.665673] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 01 00
[   71.665686] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 5 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   71.665704] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 5, async page read
[   71.665740] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x03 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=67s
[   71.665756] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 01 00
[   71.665770] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 6 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   71.665787] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 6, async page read
[   71.665824] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x03 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=67s
[   71.665841] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 07 00 00 01 00
[   71.665854] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 7 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   71.665872] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 7, async page read
[   71.665905] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x03 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=67s
[   71.665921] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 01 00
[   71.665934] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 4 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   71.665952] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 4, async page read
[   71.666096] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   71.666124] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[   71.666194] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   71.666217] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 1, async page read
[   71.667041]  sda: unable to read partition table
[   71.667248] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[   71.707351] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   71.707749] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD
[   71.707768] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 01 00
[   71.707786] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 4 inflight: CMD
[   71.707799] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 07 00 00 01 00
[   71.707812] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD
[   71.707824] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 01 00
[   71.707837] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 6 inflight: CMD
[   71.707848] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 01 00
[   71.707861] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 7 inflight: CMD
[   71.707872] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 01 00
[   71.707885] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 8 inflight: CMD
[   71.707896] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 01 00
[   71.711434] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[   71.735295] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache

Please, help me to restore original data.
Thanks.
UPDATE:
The problem was that i've detached the 2 new ones hd.
Probably Raspberry lost the loading sequence of USB drives.
Now i can reach all drives via ssh but if i detach one of two new drives all USB won't be connected on restart.
What can i do ?

"blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda"  those tend to be problems with the cable.

With 4 usb hd connected, system is ok. All 4 are seen from windows via ssh. If detach one of two 4tb no usb disk are shown by system.
